# Problem with PyQT5 in Ubuntu 22.04 not fount _ZdaPvm

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, qt5, ubuntu-22.04

I migrate my ubuntu from 20.04 to 22.04 after done all Operation System configuration i try execute my personal softwares developed in PyQT5, and my problem began.

I return to my code and after deleted and recreated the python virtual environment the bellow error is always present. At line 8 there is only the normal call of PyQT5.
[line 8 in my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRqJ3.png)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/maloi/py/choicevideos/main.py", line 8, in <module>
    from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl, Qt , QSize
ImportError: /opt/maloi/py/venv_mediaproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5/QtCore.abi3.so: undefined symbol: _ZdaPvm, version Qt_5
```

I tried found something in the internet but nothing help me. Nothing about this especific component/symbol **_ZdaPvm**

I using Python **3.10** and my pyqt5 is in version **5.15.7**

but

When I downgrade the pyqt5 to version **5.15.2** the error change to component/symbol **_ZdlPvm**

Comment: Just FYI, `_ZdaPvm` is a mangled name that means `operator delete[](void*, unsigned long)`. Maybe that helps when searching for a solution.

Comment: How did you recreated the venv? And how are you installing PyQt?

Comment: Thanks a lot @Julia . I will that point in the library code.

Comment: @musicamante the old venv was deleted and by the command ` python3 -m venv venv_mediaproject `

Activate with ` source venv_mediaproject/bin/activate `

And install with pip : ` pip install pyqt5 `

Comment: Seeing that you're using the `python3` command, I assume you also have python 2 installed? If that's so, did you try to use `pip3` instead of `pip`?

Comment: @musicamante the Ubuntu 22.04 has only python3.10. I run the command `python -V` and the output was 

(venv_mediaproject) maloi@server:/opt/maloi/qt/mediaproject/choicevideos$ python -V
Python 3.10.6

Comment: @Maloi There's probably a shared c++ library missing on your system that is required by qt5. I would suggest checking the official ubuntu 22.04 qt5 packages to see what its dependencies are. Or more simply, just use apt to install all the official pyqt5 packages required by your application, as that should automatically install all the necessary missing dependencies.

Comment: Thanks a lot @ekhumoro , the path is use the OS libraries instead of pyqt5 in the venv . 

But I have to do a workaround put a soft link from OS libraries to my venv.

'sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev libqt5multimedia5-plugins && sudo rm -r /opt/maloi/qt/mediaproject/venv_mediaproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5 && ln -f -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5 /opt/maloi/qt/mediaproject/venv_mediaproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/ '

Answer (score 1):

Thanks a lot @ekhumoro , the path is use the OS libraries instead of pyqt5 in the venv .

But I have to do a workaround put a soft link from OS libraries to my venv.

```
sudo apt-get install pyqt5-dev libqt5multimedia5-plugins && \
sudo rm -r /opt/maloi/qt/mediaproject/venv_mediaproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/PyQt5 && \
ln -f -s /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/PyQt5 /opt/maloi/qt/mediaproject/venv_mediaproject/lib/python3.10/site-packages/
```

Now the PYQT5 working well in my personal project, and executing media better than PyQT6.